# Не видно поиска за полосой z-index

Tags: html, css

http://vk.cc/3cejAt

Вверху сайта черная полоса, ее z-index 11000. За ней находится поиск, z-index которого 12500 ("blockpolnaya5566"). В чем причина?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поиск лежит в блоке дива с z-индексом 6:

```
<div style="
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 1400px;
    height: 55px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -697px;
    z-index: 6;
">
```

Comment: Вы герой, что не поленились искать. Я посмотрел тот код и сразу же закрыл его.